# Identification of an insect from midwest US

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, hemiptera

I have been seeing them more and more frequently indoors.  I am currently in the Midwest United States, weather has been unusually warm for December, and there are many trees nearby. Can someone please help identify this?

The pictures are of the same bug, but from different angles.

[image: BUG!!!!!!!!!!][image: BUG!!!!]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Brown marmorated stink bug** (*Halyomorpha halys*):

[image: bmsb-http://bugguide.net]

See [here](http://www.invasivespeciesinfo.gov/animals/stinkbug.shtml), [here](http://www.ipm.ucdavis.edu/PMG/PESTNOTES/pn74169.html), [here](http://ento.psu.edu/extension/factsheets/brown-marmorated-stink-bug) or [here](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/veg/bean/brown_marmorated_stink_bug.htm) for information.

These have become hugely invasive in the Northeast and Mid-Atlantic (and slowly Southeast) portions of the U.S. as well as along the West Coast.

The brown marmorated stink bug (*Halyomorpha halys*) is native to Eastern Asia, and likely 1st started spreading around the U.S. in Pennsylvania in the early 2000s.

[image: bmsb map - wikipedia.com]

Finally, you can see an image of the life stages of *H. halys* [here](http://ipm.uconn.edu/documents/raw2/html/images/clip_image001_020.jpg).

**Update**:

Just for clarification, other brown stink bugs do exist and can be easily confused with *H. halys*. [This article from UF IFAS](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/veg/bean/brown_marmorated_stink_bug.htm), for example, demonstrates how to differentiate *H. halys* from *Euschistus servus*:

[image]

See [here](http://pubs.cahnrs.wsu.edu/publications/pubs/fs079e/) and [here](https://entnemdept.ifas.ufl.edu/Hodges/FL_FD/Documents/BMSB.pdf) for additional ID tips and further reading.

Comment: Though the brown marmorated stink bug is non-native and hugely invasive, the bug's 'ick'  factor is not as bad as the native stink bugs that smell WAY worse! I guess the difference is, people rarely find native species indoors while these Asian ones infest homes  in the winter, bringing them into closer contact with most people.

Comment: Also if you see one of these insects, please consider reporting it! Though the battle is likely lost, there are still attempts to actively manage against the spread of these stink bugs. Google "report brown marmorated stink bug" and find a local organization or university that is collecting data in your area /region

Comment: I've been seeing them for two decades in the Pacific Northwest!

Comment: General info about some common stink bugs foudn in the midwestern US: [Stink Bugs of Ohio Soybean](https://aginsects.osu.edu/sites/aginsects/files/imce/Stink%20bugs%20of%20Ohio%20Jan%2018%202018%20Online.pdf)

Comment: I'm in the middle of Europe and just found one. Great.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer a quick search shows this insect was found in Europe as early as 2007 ([Wermelinger et al., 2008](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228912610)). [Zhu et al. (2012)](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0031246) created predictive models of their range expansion 8 years ago, which predicted spread throughout much of Europe (See Fig 6). [Leskey & Nielsen, (2018)](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev-ento-020117-043226) confirm that *H. halys* has established populations in many European countries as of 2018. (See map in Fig 1).

Comment: @theforestecologist Thanks. I'm in Luxembourg, 400km northwards even, directly east the yellow blotch covering the Ardennes region in Figure 5 of [Zhu et al.](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0031246). Well done.